# How can I remove properties without using option(?) in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have problems about removing properties.
For example:

```
type Person<GN>  = {
    getName: GN extends never ? never :  GN,
}

const foo =  <GN>(person: Person<GN>) => person

const first = foo({}) // should work

const second = foo({
    getName: (name: string) => name,
})
```

In this case first doesn't need getName property. How can I solve that.

---

Using optional '?' property it will cause unclearly output.
For example

```
type Person<GN>  = {
    getName?: GN,
}

const foo =  <GN>(person: Person<GN>) => person

const first = foo({}) // should work
first.getName // shouldn't exist 'getName' => but still have

const second = foo({
    getName: (name: string) => name,
})

second.getName // should exist getName but in this case is optional property
```

How can I make clearly output?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want `first` type to be inferred as `{}`, and `second` type as `{ getName: (name: string) => string; }` ?

Here is one way to do that:

```
type Person<GN> = { getName: GN }

const foo = <GN, P extends Partial<Person<GN>>>(person: P) => person;

const first = foo({}) // const first: {}

const second = foo({  // const second: { getName: (name: string) => string; }
    getName: (name: string) => name,
})
```